# jest toBeInstanceOf Expected constructor: Array Received constructor: Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using native `fetch` in `node:18` (with typescript CommonJS)

```js
async function listCollections() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json();
}
```

And this endpoint returns array.

I was expect that

```js
expect(collections).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
```

will pass, but in jest tests I see

```js
    let collections = await chroma.listCollections()
    console.log(collections);
    // display [ { name: 'test', metadata: null } ] as object not string as expected

    expect(Array.isArray(collections)).toBeTruthy()
    // yes as expected

    expect(collections.constructor.name).toStrictEqual('Array')
    // yes as expected

    expect(collections).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
    // there is fail

    expect(new Array()).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
    // it works correctly

    expect([]).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
    // it also works
```

I added three console logs

```js
    console.log(collections.constructor);
    console.log([].constructor);
    console.log(Array);
```

and all shows

```
    [Function: Array]
```

I checked source code of `jest` and found that difference is in `instanceof` here are next tests

```
    expect(collections instanceof Array).toBeFalsy();
    expect([] instanceof Array).toBeTruthy();
    expect(new Array() instanceof Array).toBeTruthy();
    expect(new Array(...collections) instanceof Array).toBeTruthy();
    expect(new Array(...collections)).toEqual(collections)
```

so collections is NOT instanceof Array. I found some explanation that `collections` probably is Array from *other context*

> JavaScript execution environments (windows, frames, etc.) are each in their own realm. This means that they have different built-ins (different global object, different constructors, etc.). This may result in unexpected results. For instance, [] instanceof window.frames[0].Array will return false, because Array.prototype !== window.frames[0].Array.prototype and arrays in the current realm inherit from the former.

> This may not make sense at first, but for scripts dealing with multiple frames or windows, and passing objects from one context to another via functions, this will be a valid and strong issue. For instance, you can securely check if a given object is in fact an Array using Array.isArray(), neglecting which realm it comes from.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

but I still do not understand what exactly is `collection` in my code and how this `Array` is different from normal `Array`.

---

As a workaround I am using function that override constructor but still will appreciate links to any docs/code related to `Array` from `fetch`.

```js
function repack(value: unknown): any {
  if(Boolean(value) && typeof value === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return new Array(...value);
    } else {
      return {...value};
    }
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```